# How do I get Mercury Editor to redirect to a new resource?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, mercury-editor

After watching [RailsCast #296 about Mercury Editor](http://railscasts.com/episodes/296-mercury-editor), I am trying to get the editor to redirect to a newly created resource.

I can already redirect on the client-side using JS and `window.location.href=`. But for a new resource, I cannot "guess" its URL on the client-side. I need it to be in the server response.

However, the problem is that I don't see the possibility of using the server response in the editor. No matter what the controller renders, the server response is [discarded](https://github.com/jejacks0n/mercury/blob/c4765034e47825c38530b2dd9adf7a05e5c325bb/app/assets/javascripts/mercury/page_editor.js.coffee#L242) by Mercury instead of used as an argument to my function for `mercury:saved`.

Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to do this on update by sending a valid JSON string back. I would assume create works the same way. check firebug to make sure you're not getting an error in the jQuery.ajax call that Mercury uses.

posts_controller.rb

```
def mercury_update
  post = Post.find(params[:id])
  post.title = params[:content][:post_title][:value]
  post.body = params[:content][:post_body][:value]
  post.save!
  render text: '{"url":"'+ post_path(post.slug) +'"}'
end
```

mercury.js:

```
  jQuery(window).on('mercury:ready', function() {
    Mercury.on('saved', function() {
       window.location.href = arguments[1].url      
    });
  });
```

note: I'm using [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) to slug my posts

Comment: I think you mean `arguments[1].url` above.

Comment: @jordanpg, I think you mean `render :json => {:url => post_path(post.slug)}` below

Comment: @awendt- seems like this answer is useful to people, do you think you can accept it?

Answer (score 1):

Redirecting on the server side doesn't work because the save button is just an `jQuery.ajax` call:

```
// page_editor.js
PageEditor.prototype.save = function(callback) {
      var data, method, options, url, _ref, _ref1,
        _this = this;
      url = (_ref = (_ref1 = this.saveUrl) != null ? _ref1 : Mercury.saveUrl) != null ? _ref : this.iframeSrc();
      data = this.serialize();
      data = {
        content: data
      };
      if (this.options.saveMethod === 'POST') {
        method = 'POST';
      } else {
        method = 'PUT';
        data['_method'] = method;
      }
      Mercury.log('saving', data);
      options = {
        headers: Mercury.ajaxHeaders(),
        type: method,
        dataType: this.options.saveDataType,
        data: data,
        success: function(response) {
          Mercury.changes = false;
          Mercury.trigger('saved', response);
          if (typeof callback === 'function') {
            return callback();
          }
        },
        error: function(response) {
          Mercury.trigger('save_failed', response);
          return Mercury.notify('Mercury was unable to save to the url: %s', url);
        }
      };
      if (this.options.saveStyle !== 'form') {
        options['data'] = jQuery.toJSON(data);
        options['contentType'] = 'application/json';
      }
      return jQuery.ajax(url, options);
    };
```

So your redirect is sent to the `success` callback, but the page doesn't actually re-render, as with any successful AJAX request. The author discusses overriding this very function [here](https://github.com/jejacks0n/mercury/wiki/Extending-Mercury).  It also looks like there might be some room to maneuver here by passing a callback function to `save`.

Btw, another way to do what @corneliusk suggests is:

```
render { json: {url: post_path(post.slug)} }
```

Either way, the response body is passed as an argument to the function in the `mercury:saved` callback.